# Is it possible to debug NDK code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

When I run my application and some exception happens I start debugging it, and dive into framework code, but at some point I see that exception (or unexpected behaviour) happens in native code. Is it possible to pull NDK sources in android studio and continue going through breakpoints?

Particularly when I work with AssetManager and one of its native methods returns that there is no specific file, but I know that this file exists, so is there a way to debug that native method?

Comment: With the latest versions of Android Studio and the NDK, this "should just work" (TM). What have you tried?

Comment: @NuSkooler Yes I tried, but how can I open native method? when I press on normal method Cmd+B, it opens android sources, but it won't happen for native sources

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line. It's like programming **usual** `.cpp` projects.